# My app crash when try to pass data from an activity to a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to pass a string from an ativity to a fragment so I can use it in the AsynkTask implemented there but the app crashes every time I add this line to the fragment code : `String id_client= bundle.getString("client_id");` ... here is the fragment code

```
public class FragmentContrat extends Fragment {
    View view ;


    public FragmentContrat() {
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.contrat_fragment,container,false);


        Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();

        String id_client= bundle.getString("client_id");

        if(bundle!=null){

            Log.d("s","fine");

        }else {

            Log.d("s","problem");
        }

        return view ;

}
```

I added the if statement to check if the bundle is null and actually it is .

Here is the activity code where I sent the data :

```
public class DetailsContrat extends AppCompatActivity {

    TabLayout details_tab;
    AppBarLayout details_bar;
    ViewPager details_pager;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_details_contrat);

        details_tab=(TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.details_tab);
        details_bar=(AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.details_bar);
        details_pager=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.details_pager);

        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.AddFragment(new FragmentContrat(),"MON CONTRAT");
        adapter.AddFragment(new FragmentVehicule(),"MA VOITURE");
        adapter.AddFragment(new FragmentGaranties(),"MES GARANTIES");
        details_pager.setAdapter(adapter);
        details_tab.setupWithViewPager(details_pager);


        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("id_client","my name");
        FragmentContrat fragmentContrat = new FragmentContrat();
        fragmentContrat.setArguments(bundle);


    }


}
```

Logcat error

```
2019-03-16 00:13:39.221 1699-5578/system_process E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
2019-03-16 00:13:39.222 1699-5578/system_process E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
2019-03-16 00:13:40.607 1699-1860/system_process E/TaskPersister: File error accessing recents directory (directory doesn't exist?).
```

Comment: print your log error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I find the solution ... in the main activity I was creating a new object of the fragment and adding it to the adapter 
`adapter.AddFragment(new FragmentContrat(),"MON CONTRAT");` 
 ... then I was creating another object of the fragment 
`FragmentContrat fragmentContrat = new FragmentContrat();` 
and setting the bundle there ... so actually the bundle of the first fragment which I passed to the adapter is null which caused the crash ... the right way is to creat a new object of the fragment , set the bundle then add it to the adapter like this

```
    public class DetailsContrat extends AppCompatActivity {

        TabLayout details_tab;
        AppBarLayout details_bar;
        ViewPager details_pager;




        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_details_contrat);

            details_tab=(TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.details_tab);
            details_bar=(AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.details_bar);
            details_pager=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.details_pager);


            /* Creating new object and setting its arguments here */
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("id_client","my name");
            FragmentContrat fragmentContrat = new FragmentContrat();
            fragmentContrat.setArguments(bundle);


            ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new 
            ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

            /* Adding the object already created and setted here */
            adapter.AddFragment(fragmentContrat ,"MON CONTRAT");

            adapter.AddFragment(new FragmentVehicule(),"MA VOITURE");
            adapter.AddFragment(new FragmentGaranties(),"MES GARANTIES");
            details_pager.setAdapter(adapter);
            details_tab.setupWithViewPager(details_pager);





        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your key is incorrect in your activity code.

Change

```
bundle.putString("id_client","my name");
```

to

```
bundle.putString("client_id","my name");
```

The key has to be the same in both the activity and fragment.

Comment: thanks for the reply ... but it didn't work the app keep crashing when I add the line and works when I remove it .

Comment: where is your log?

Comment: @RVP-milan I can't see where you need a directory in your provided code blocks, so I can't understand why you're getting the error you edited into your original post.

Comment: I have no idea ... it's really frustrating .

Comment: @RVP-milan did you managed to get it fixed? If so what fixed it?

Comment: Yes I did ... in the main activity I was creating a new object of the fragment and adding it  to the adapter <" adapter.AddFragment(new FragmentContrat(),"MON CONTRAT"); > ... then I was creating another object of the fragment < FragmentContrat fragmentContrat = new FragmentContrat(); > and setting the bundle in it ... so actually the bundle of the first fragment which I passed to the adapter is null which caused the crash ... the right way is to creat a new object of the fragment , set the bundle then add it to the adapter , I'll post the solution under this comment in an answer .

Comment: @RVP-Milan nice one, Thanks for replying back